# React Downshift: как подключиться к массиву, находящимся в сети

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, jsx

Пишу небольшой интерфейс к приложению с картой и отображению адресов с координатами и подсказками в input, все как положено(все как у uber). Пожалуйста, кто знаком с плагином Downshift, который выдает подсказки от ввода в input.

Есть код компонента этого Downshift:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Downshift from 'downshift';


function getStreetList (callback){

  let requestToStreets = new Request(
    'https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/address',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token 1e4cb9c1bbeff03271767fb32b42cfb6721e8927',
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'query': 'Санкт-Петербург',
      })
    }
  );

  fetch(requestToStreets)
      .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
      .then(function(data){callback(data.suggestions)});

  }

let streetsList;

getStreetList((streets) => {
  streetsList = streets;
});


class SearchInput extends React.Component{

  render(){
  return (
    <DownshiftWrapper itemToString={item => (item ? item.value : '')}>
    {({
       getInputProps,
       getItemProps,
       getLabelProps,
       getMenuProps,
       isOpen,
       inputValue,
       highlightedIndex,
       selectedItem,
    }) =>(
     <div>
       <SearchInputWrapper {...getInputProps()} />
       <StreetList {...getMenuProps()}>
          {isOpen
            ? streetsList
                .filter(item => !inputValue || item.value.includes(inputValue))
                .map((item, index) => (
                  <li
                    {...getItemProps({
                      key: item,
                      index,
                      item,
                      style: {
                        borderBottomColor:
                          highlightedIndex === index ? '#EFB8AF' : '#EEE',
                      },
                    })}
                  >
                    <span>streetsList.value</span>
                  <span>{streetsList.data.region}</span> //МЕСТО ОШИБКИ!!

                  </li>
                ))
            : null}
        </StreetList>
      </div>
    )}
    </DownshiftWrapper>
  )}
}

export default SearchInput
```

Избавил вас от стилей styled component(названия тегов измененные из-за этого плагина). В общем, Downshift позволяет выдать из массива, который я получил fetch - запросом, свойство value. Если что объект который я запросил выглядит примерно так:

```
{
    "suggestions": [
        {
            "value": "г Москва, ул Хабаровская",
            "unrestricted_value": "г Москва, ул Хабаровская",
            "data": {
                "postal_code": null,
                "country": "Россия",
                "country_iso_code": "RU",
                "federal_district": null,
                "region_fias_id": "0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5",
                "region_kladr_id": "7700000000000",
                "region_iso_code": "RU-MOW",
                "region_with_type": "г Москва",
                "region_type": "г",
                "region_type_full": "город",
                "region": "Москва",
                "area_fias_id": null,
                "area_kladr_id": null,
                "area_with_type": null,
                "area_type": null,
                "area_type_full": null,
                "area": null,
                "city_fias_id": "0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5",
                "city_kladr_id": "7700000000000",
                "city_with_type": "г Москва",
                "city_type": "г",
                "city_type_full": "город",
                "city": "Москва",
                "city_area": null,
                "city_district_fias_id": null,
                "city_district_kladr_id": null,
                "city_district_with_type": null,
                "city_district_type": null,
                "city_district_type_full": null,
                "city_district": null,
                "settlement_fias_id": null,
                "settlement_kladr_id": null,
                "settlement_with_type": null,
                "settlement_type": null,
                "settlement_type_full": null,
                "settlement": null,
                "street_fias_id": "32fcb102-2a50-44c9-a00e-806420f448ea",
                "street_kladr_id": "77000000000713400",
                "street_with_type": "ул Хабаровская",
                "street_type": "ул",
                "street_type_full": "улица",
                "street": "Хабаровская",
                "house_fias_id": null,
                "house_kladr_id": null,
                "house_type": null,
                "house_type_full": null,
                "house": null,
                "block_type": null,
                "block_type_full": null,
                "block": null,
                "flat_type": null,
                "flat_type_full": null,
                "flat": null,
                "flat_area": null,
                "square_meter_price": null,
                "flat_price": null,
                "postal_box": null,
                "fias_id": "32fcb102-2a50-44c9-a00e-806420f448ea",
                "fias_code": null,
                "fias_level": "7",
                "fias_actuality_state": null,
                "kladr_id": "77000000000713400",
                "geoname_id": null,
                "capital_marker": "0",
                "okato": "45263564000",
                "oktmo": "45305000",
                "tax_office": "7718",
                "tax_office_legal": "7718",
                "timezone": null,
                "geo_lat": null,
                "geo_lon": null,
                "beltway_hit": null,
                "beltway_distance": null,
                "metro": null,
                "qc_geo": null,
                "qc_complete": null,
                "qc_house": null,
                "history_values": [
                    "ул Черненко"
                ],
                "unparsed_parts": null,
                "source": null,
                "qc": null
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Вопрос: Downshift показывает мне значение {streetsList.value}, но отказывает показывать {streetsList.data.region}, выдавая ошибку - Cannot read property 'region' of undefined. Но data.region есть в ответе. Помогите, как мне разделить на части ответ, если downshift не видит ничего кроме огромного ответа data.value.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ оказался простым, брать значения нужно просто из item функции map:

```
<span>{item.data.street}</span>
<span>{item.data.region}</span>
```